# Why doesn't my piece of code work?

Tags: algorithms, algorithmic

I'm trying to write a simple piece of code like:

```
\begin{algorithm} 
\caption{ALG 1} 
\label{system} 
\begin{algorithmic} 
    \For{$each n \in V$}
        M \leftarrow Dijkstra(n);
    \EndFor


\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

I included `\usepackage{algorithm}` and `\usepackage{algorithmic}` but it doesn't work.

I obtain:

```
LaTeX Error: Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \For 

l.81     \For
             {$each n \in V$}
.
```

Where is the error?

Comment: There's a confusig bunch of `algorithm` - related packages. Have you tried `algorithm2e` instead as package?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax you're using is that of `algpseudocode`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{ALG 1}
\label{system}
\begin{algorithmic}
    \For{each $n \in V$}
        $M \leftarrow \operatorname{Dijkstra}(n)$;
    \EndFor
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Note the math mode around the middle line and `each` outside of it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

see `texdoc algorithmic`  the command is `\FOR` or `\FORALL` not `\For`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm} 
\caption{ALG 1} 
\label{system} 
\begin{algorithmic} 
    \FORALL{$n \in V$}
      \STATE   $M \leftarrow \mathrm{Dijkstra}(n)$;
    \ENDFOR
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```